# when I try to pip install pywhatkit it gives me a weird error

Tags: python, pip

I been trying to use pip to install pywhatkit on Mac OS with this command `pip install pywhatkit`
it gives me the following error

---

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Users/benhogan/Desktop/python/elvis-pytts3/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-record-wvm04vhq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/benhogan/Desktop/python/elvis-pytts3/venv/include/site/python3.8/Pillow
cwd: /private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/
Complete output (179 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/_deprecate.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/FitsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/**main**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/PIL
running egg_info
writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to src/Pillow.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.c'
warning: no files found matching '*.h'
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

```
The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/setup.py", line 995, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/Users/benhogan/Desktop/python/elvis-pytts3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/benhogan/Desktop/python/elvis-pytts3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 561, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/benhogan/Desktop/python/elvis-pytts3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 87, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/setup.py", line 810, in build_extensions
    raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/setup.py", line 1015, in <module>
    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/benhogan/Desktop/python/elvis-pytts3/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-install-n_x234rv/pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zc/jgby2l1n4yq2c4l5hcs6_5b80000gn/T/pip-record-wvm04vhq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/benhogan/Desktop/python/elvis-pytts3/venv/include/site/python3.8/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error says you're missing a library which is needed by `pillow`. Please follow the install instructions of `pillow` and install the missing requirements, before installing `pywhatkit`.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-on-macos

```
    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

To quote from the `pillow` install instructions:

> The easiest way to install external libraries is via Homebrew (https://brew.sh/). After
> you install Homebrew, run:
>
> ```
> brew install libjpeg libtiff little-cms2 openjpeg webp
> ```

Comment: thank you I feel stupid now it worked (note I actually did try to pip install pillow but I guess I did wrong ) anyway thanks